# Setting Parent/Project/Release Context via bootstrap parameters

Tags: rally, code-rally

I'm making good progress on creating a generic javascript to build a task list/tree that ultimately be run on a wiki. The challenge is that I would like to have multiple instances of this script running pointing the various subprojects that are layered under different projects in a workspace.  Is there a way to pass the context parameters (Parent Project,Project, Iteration, Release etc.) via the Rally.launchapp/bootstrap? That way there is a quick common spot to tune this via the wiki markup. Thanks! Mark

Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
        name: "RallyGrid",
        parentRepos: " "
    });
});enter code here

Comment: Apps currently only know how to get their context from url parameters.  Were you able to get your app running in an iframe so you can do that?